# I can't send email using CodeIgniter and namecaep

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't send an email on the host (https://www.namecheap.com). used `CodeIgniter` framework

```
 $config = Array(
  'protocol' => 'HTTP',// also used smtp
  'smtp_host' => 'mail.sss.com.ng',
  'smtp_port' => 26,
  'smtp_user' => 'ss@sss.com.ng', // change it to yours
  'smtp_pass' => '3333333', // change it to yours
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
  'wordwrap' => TRUE
  );


    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      $this->email->from('sss@sss.com.ng'); // change it to yours
      $this->email->to($to);// change it to yours
      $this->email->subject($subject);
      $this->email->message('6666');
      if($this->email->send())
      {
        echo 'Email sent.';
      }
      else
      {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
      }

    }
```

I am getting this error:

> error An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be
>   configured to send mail using this method.
>
> User-Agent: CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0):

Put below configuration this will work.

```
$config['useragent']        = 'CodeIgniter';  
$config['protocol']         = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']        = '*****';
$config['smtp_port']        = '**';
$config['smtp_user']        = '**';
$config['smtp_pass']        = '****';
$config['wordwrap']         = TRUE;
$config['smtp_timeout']     = 5;
$config['wrapchars']        = 76;
$config['charset']          = 'utf-8';
$config['crlf']             = "\r\n";
$config['validate']         = FALSE;
$config['mailtype']         = 'html';
$config['priority']         = '3';
$config['newline']          = "\r\n";
```

Thanks